# .NET LOH Compaction

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have been wondering why after the following code the GC does not recover the memory ?

background:
The application I am using uses much of large arrays and memory grows > 1GiB where the memory usage should be much smaller because the used arrays are discarded immediatelly after an operation is performed (similar as in this case).

```
{
    Random r = new Random();
    byte[] arr = new byte[100 * 1024 * 1024]; r.NextBytes(arr); //allocate 100MiB
    arr = null;
}

GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
//should expect memory recovery...
```

I am using Memory Diagnostics Tools within Visual Studio and I have also been looking to the Windows Task Manager.
This code is chosen because it reflects the behavior of the app which allocates large arrays, then sets them to null, then again allocates (bunch of images).
The behavior I am experiencing is constant memory increase, then suddenly memory consumption drop (I guess after the GC collects those objects).

This, however, leads to frequent hangs on a system that does not have too much RAM. Therefore, it would be helpful if the GC can collect those objects more frequently.

Comment: It is just bad repro code.  You are asking the LOH to compact but there is nothing left to compact.  You'd have to intentionally create holes, that takes allocating multiple arrays and ensuring that *some* of them are unused before you collect.

Comment: Also you are likely using task manager to measure memory usage without good understanding what it actually shows... Consider to clarify how you measure memory usage and what you actually expect to happen